# Uncaught TypeError: g(...).block is not a function

Tags: javascript

Getting this error on the checkout page of WooCommerce store.

```html
checkout.min.js?ver=4.3.1:186 Uncaught TypeError: g(...).block is not a function
    at update_checkout_action (checkout.min.js?ver=4.3.1:186)
```

Points to this line.

```js
 g(".woocommerce-checkout-payment,.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table").block({
```

I'm new to JS and for the life of me can't figure out a solution. This is the URL for the page http://shannonp12.sg-host.com/checkout/ I'm unable to contact the original developer. Full snippet below.

```js
jQuery(function(g) {
    if ("undefined" == typeof wc_checkout_params)
        return !1;
    var v = {
        dirtyInput: !1,
        selectedPaymentMethod: !1,
        xhr: !1,
        $order_review: g("#order_review"),
        $checkout_form: g("form.checkout"),
        init: function() {
            g(document.body).bind("update_checkout", this.update_checkout),
            g(document.body).bind("init_checkout", this.init_checkout),
            this.$checkout_form.on("click", 'input[name="payment_method"]', this.payment_method_selected),
            g(document.body).hasClass("woocommerce-order-pay") && (this.$order_review.on("click", 'input[name="payment_method"]', this.payment_method_selected),
            this.$order_review.on("submit", this.submitOrder),
            this.$order_review.attr("novalidate", "novalidate")),
            this.$checkout_form.attr("novalidate", "novalidate"),
            this.$checkout_form.on("submit", this.submit),
            this.$checkout_form.on("input validate change", ".input-text, select, input:checkbox", this.validate_field),
            this.$checkout_form.on("update", this.trigger_update_checkout),
            this.$checkout_form.on("change", 'select.shipping_method, input[name^="shipping_method"], #ship-to-different-address input, .update_totals_on_change select, .update_totals_on_change input[type="radio"], .update_totals_on_change input[type="checkbox"]', this.trigger_update_checkout),
            this.$checkout_form.on("change", ".address-field select", this.input_changed),
            this.$checkout_form.on("change", ".address-field input.input-text, .update_totals_on_change input.input-text", this.maybe_input_changed),
            this.$checkout_form.on("keydown", ".address-field input.input-text, .update_totals_on_change input.input-text", this.queue_update_checkout),
            this.$checkout_form.on("change", "#ship-to-different-address input", this.ship_to_different_address),
            this.$checkout_form.find("#ship-to-different-address input").change(),
            this.init_payment_methods(),
            "1" === wc_checkout_params.is_checkout && g(document.body).trigger("init_checkout"),
            "yes" === wc_checkout_params.option_guest_checkout && g("input#createaccount").change(this.toggle_create_account).change()
        },
        init_payment_methods: function() {
            var e = g(".woocommerce-checkout").find('input[name="payment_method"]');
            1 === e.length && e.eq(0).hide(),
            v.selectedPaymentMethod && g("#" + v.selectedPaymentMethod).prop("checked", !0),
            0 === e.filter(":checked").length && e.eq(0).prop("checked", !0);
            var t = e.filter(":checked").eq(0).prop("id");
            1 < e.length && g('div.payment_box:not(".' + t + '")').filter(":visible").slideUp(0),
            e.filter(":checked").eq(0).trigger("click")
        },
        get_payment_method: function() {
            return v.$checkout_form.find('input[name="payment_method"]:checked').val()
        },
        payment_method_selected: function(e) {
            if (e.stopPropagation(),
            1 < g(".payment_methods input.input-radio").length) {
                var t = g("div.payment_box." + g(this).attr("ID"))
                  , o = g(this).is(":checked");
                o && !t.is(":visible") && (g("div.payment_box").filter(":visible").slideUp(230),
                o && t.slideDown(230))
            } else
                g("div.payment_box").show();
            g(this).data("order_button_text") ? g("#place_order").text(g(this).data("order_button_text")) : g("#place_order").text(g("#place_order").data("value"));
            var c = g('.woocommerce-checkout input[name="payment_method"]:checked').attr("id");
            c !== v.selectedPaymentMethod && g(document.body).trigger("payment_method_selected"),
            v.selectedPaymentMethod = c
        },
        toggle_create_account: function() {
            g("div.create-account").hide(),
            g(this).is(":checked") && (g("#account_password").val("").change(),
            g("div.create-account").slideDown())
        },
        init_checkout: function() {
            g(document.body).trigger("update_checkout")
        },
        maybe_input_changed: function(e) {
            v.dirtyInput && v.input_changed(e)
        },
        input_changed: function(e) {
            v.dirtyInput = e.target,
            v.maybe_update_checkout()
        },
        queue_update_checkout: function(e) {
            if (9 === (e.keyCode || e.which || 0))
                return !0;
            v.dirtyInput = this,
            v.reset_update_checkout_timer(),
            v.updateTimer = setTimeout(v.maybe_update_checkout, "1000")
        },
        trigger_update_checkout: function() {
            v.reset_update_checkout_timer(),
            v.dirtyInput = !1,
            g(document.body).trigger("update_checkout")
        },
        maybe_update_checkout: function() {
            var e = !0;
            if (g(v.dirtyInput).length) {
                var t = g(v.dirtyInput).closest("div").find(".address-field.validate-required");
                t.length && t.each(function() {
                    "" === g(this).find("input.input-text").val() && (e = !1)
                })
            }
            e && v.trigger_update_checkout()
        },
        ship_to_different_address: function() {
            g("div.shipping_address").hide(),
            g(this).is(":checked") && g("div.shipping_address").slideDown()
        },
        reset_update_checkout_timer: function() {
            clearTimeout(v.updateTimer)
        },
        is_valid_json: function(e) {
            try {
                var t = g.parseJSON(e);
                return t && "object" == typeof t
            } catch (o) {
                return !1
            }
        },
        validate_field: function(e) {
            var t = g(this)
              , o = t.closest(".form-row")
              , c = !0
              , i = o.is(".validate-required")
              , n = o.is(".validate-email")
              , r = e.type;
            if ("input" === r && o.removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field woocommerce-invalid-email woocommerce-validated"),
            "validate" === r || "change" === r) {
                if (i && ("checkbox" !== t.attr("type") || t.is(":checked") ? "" === t.val() && (o.removeClass("woocommerce-validated").addClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field"),
                c = !1) : (o.removeClass("woocommerce-validated").addClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field"),
                c = !1)),
                n)
                    if (t.val())
                        new RegExp(/^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[0-9a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i).test(t.val()) || (o.removeClass("woocommerce-validated").addClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-email"),
                        c = !1);
                c && o.removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field woocommerce-invalid-email").addClass("woocommerce-validated")
            }
        },
        update_checkout: function(e, t) {
            v.reset_update_checkout_timer(),
            v.updateTimer = setTimeout(v.update_checkout_action, "5", t)
        },
        update_checkout_action: function(e) {
            if (v.xhr && v.xhr.abort(),
            0 !== g("form.checkout").length) {
                e = void 0 !== e ? e : {
                    update_shipping_method: !0
                };
                var t = g("#billing_country").val()
                  , o = g("#billing_state").val()
                  , c = g(":input#billing_postcode").val()
                  , i = g("#billing_city").val()
                  , n = g(":input#billing_address_1").val()
                  , r = g(":input#billing_address_2").val()
                  , a = t
                  , u = o
                  , d = c
                  , s = i
                  , m = n
                  , l = r
                  , h = g(v.$checkout_form).find(".address-field.validate-required:visible")
                  , p = !0;
                h.length && h.each(function() {
                    "" === g(this).find(":input").val() && (p = !1)
                }),
                g("#ship-to-different-address").find("input").is(":checked") && (a = g("#shipping_country").val(),
                u = g("#shipping_state").val(),
                d = g(":input#shipping_postcode").val(),
                s = g("#shipping_city").val(),
                m = g(":input#shipping_address_1").val(),
                l = g(":input#shipping_address_2").val());
                var _ = {
                    security: wc_checkout_params.update_order_review_nonce,
                    payment_method: v.get_payment_method(),
                    country: t,
                    state: o,
                    postcode: c,
                    city: i,
                    address: n,
                    address_2: r,
                    s_country: a,
                    s_state: u,
                    s_postcode: d,
                    s_city: s,
                    s_address: m,
                    s_address_2: l,
                    has_full_address: p,
                    post_data: g("form.checkout").serialize()
                };
                if (!1 !== e.update_shipping_method) {
                    var f = {};
                    g('select.shipping_method, input[name^="shipping_method"][type="radio"]:checked, input[name^="shipping_method"][type="hidden"]').each(function() {
                        f[g(this).data("index")] = g(this).val()
                    }),
                    _.shipping_method = f
                }
                g(".woocommerce-checkout-payment,.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table").block({
                    message: null,
                    overlayCSS: {
                        background: "#fff",
                        opacity: 0.6
                    }
                }),
                v.xhr = g.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: wc_checkout_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "update_order_review"),
                    data: _,
                    success: function(e) {
                        if (e && !0 === e.reload)
                            window.location.reload();
                        else {
                            g(".woocommerce-NoticeGroup-updateOrderReview").remove();
                            var t = g("#terms").prop("checked")
                              , o = {};
                            if (g(".payment_box :input").each(function() {
                                var e = g(this).attr("id");
                                e && (-1 !== g.inArray(g(this).attr("type"), ["checkbox", "radio"]) ? o[e] = g(this).prop("checked") : o[e] = g(this).val())
                            }),
                            e && e.fragments && (g.each(e.fragments, function(e, t) {
                                v.fragments && v.fragments[e] === t || g(e).replaceWith(t),
                                g(e).unblock()
                            }),
                            v.fragments = e.fragments),
                            t && g("#terms").prop("checked", !0),
                            g.isEmptyObject(o) || g(".payment_box :input").each(function() {
                                var e = g(this).attr("id");
                                e && (-1 !== g.inArray(g(this).attr("type"), ["checkbox", "radio"]) ? g(this).prop("checked", o[e]).change() : -1 !== g.inArray(g(this).attr("type"), ["select"]) ? g(this).val(o[e]).change() : null !== g(this).val() && 0 === g(this).val().length && g(this).val(o[e]).change())
                            }),
                            e && "failure" === e.result) {
                                var c = g("form.checkout");
                                g(".woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-message").remove(),
                                e.messages ? c.prepend('<div class="woocommerce-NoticeGroup woocommerce-NoticeGroup-updateOrderReview">' + e.messages + "</div>") : c.prepend(e),
                                c.find(".input-text, select, input:checkbox").trigger("validate").blur(),
                                v.scroll_to_notices()
                            }
                            v.init_payment_methods(),
                            g(document.body).trigger("updated_checkout", [e])
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        },
        handleUnloadEvent: function(e) {
            return -1 === navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") && !document.documentMode || (e.preventDefault(),
            undefined)
        },
        attachUnloadEventsOnSubmit: function() {
            g(window).on("beforeunload", this.handleUnloadEvent)
        },
        detachUnloadEventsOnSubmit: function() {
            g(window).unbind("beforeunload", this.handleUnloadEvent)
        },
        blockOnSubmit: function(e) {
            1 !== e.data()["blockUI.isBlocked"] && e.block({
                message: null,
                overlayCSS: {
                    background: "#fff",
                    opacity: .6
                }
            })
        },
        submitOrder: function() {
            v.blockOnSubmit(g(this))
        },
        submit: function() {
            v.reset_update_checkout_timer();
            var o = g(this);
            return o.is(".processing") || !1 !== o.triggerHandler("checkout_place_order") && !1 !== o.triggerHandler("checkout_place_order_" + v.get_payment_method()) && (o.addClass("processing"),
            v.blockOnSubmit(o),
            v.attachUnloadEventsOnSubmit(),
            g.ajaxSetup({
                dataFilter: function(e, t) {
                    if ("json" !== t)
                        return e;
                    if (v.is_valid_json(e))
                        return e;
                    var o = e.match(/{"result.*}/);
                    return null === o ? console.log("Unable to fix malformed JSON") : v.is_valid_json(o[0]) ? (console.log("Fixed malformed JSON. Original:"),
                    console.log(e),
                    e = o[0]) : console.log("Unable to fix malformed JSON"),
                    e
                }
            }),
            g.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wc_checkout_params.checkout_url,
                data: o.serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(e) {
                    v.detachUnloadEventsOnSubmit();
                    try {
                        if ("success" !== e.result || !1 === o.triggerHandler("checkout_place_order_success"))
                            throw "failure" === e.result ? "Result failure" : "Invalid response";
                        -1 === e.redirect.indexOf("https://") || -1 === e.redirect.indexOf("http://") ? window.location = e.redirect : window.location = decodeURI(e.redirect)
                    } catch (t) {
                        if (!0 === e.reload)
                            return void window.location.reload();
                        !0 === e.refresh && g(document.body).trigger("update_checkout"),
                        e.messages ? v.submit_error(e.messages) : v.submit_error('<div class="woocommerce-error">' + wc_checkout_params.i18n_checkout_error + "</div>")
                    }
                },
                error: function(e, t, o) {
                    v.detachUnloadEventsOnSubmit(),
                    v.submit_error('<div class="woocommerce-error">' + o + "</div>")
                }
            })),
            !1
        },
        submit_error: function(e) {
            g(".woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout, .woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-message").remove(),
            v.$checkout_form.prepend('<div class="woocommerce-NoticeGroup woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout">' + e + "</div>"),
            v.$checkout_form.removeClass("processing").unblock(),
            v.$checkout_form.find(".input-text, select, input:checkbox").trigger("validate").blur(),
            v.scroll_to_notices(),
            g(document.body).trigger("checkout_error")
        },
        scroll_to_notices: function() {
            var e = g(".woocommerce-NoticeGroup-updateOrderReview, .woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout");
            e.length || (e = g(".form.checkout")),
            g.scroll_to_notices(e)
        }
    }
      , e = {
        init: function() {
            g(document.body).on("click", "a.showcoupon", this.show_coupon_form),
            g(document.body).on("click", ".woocommerce-remove-coupon", this.remove_coupon),
            g("form.checkout_coupon").hide().submit(this.submit)
        },
        show_coupon_form: function() {
            return g(".checkout_coupon").slideToggle(400, function() {
                g(".checkout_coupon").find(":input:eq(0)").focus()
            }),
            !1
        },
        submit: function() {
            var t = g(this);
            if (t.is(".processing"))
                return !1;
            t.addClass("processing").block({
                message: null,
                overlayCSS: {
                    background: "#fff",
                    opacity: .6
                }
            });
            var o = {
                security: wc_checkout_params.apply_coupon_nonce,
                coupon_code: t.find('input[name="coupon_code"]').val()
            };
            return g.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wc_checkout_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "apply_coupon"),
                data: o,
                success: function(e) {
                    g(".woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-message").remove(),
                    t.removeClass("processing").unblock(),
                    e && (t.before(e),
                    t.slideUp(),
                    g(document.body).trigger("applied_coupon_in_checkout", [o.coupon_code]),
                    g(document.body).trigger("update_checkout", {
                        update_shipping_method: !1
                    }))
                },
                dataType: "html"
            }),
            !1
        },
        remove_coupon: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var t = g(this).parents(".woocommerce-checkout-review-order")
              , o = g(this).data("coupon");
            t.addClass("processing").block({
                message: null,
                overlayCSS: {
                    background: "#fff",
                    opacity: .6
                }
            });
            var c = {
                security: wc_checkout_params.remove_coupon_nonce,
                coupon: o
            };
            g.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wc_checkout_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "remove_coupon"),
                data: c,
                success: function(e) {
                    g(".woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-message").remove(),
                    t.removeClass("processing").unblock(),
                    e && (g("form.woocommerce-checkout").before(e),
                    g(document.body).trigger("update_checkout", {
                        update_shipping_method: !1
                    }),
                    g("form.checkout_coupon").find('input[name="coupon_code"]').val(""))
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    wc_checkout_params.debug_mode && console.log(e.responseText)
                },
                dataType: "html"
            })
        }
    }
      , t = {
        init: function() {
            g(document.body).on("click", "a.showlogin", this.show_login_form)
        },
        show_login_form: function() {
            return g("form.login, form.woocommerce-form--login").slideToggle(),
            !1
        }
    }
      , o = {
        init: function() {
            g(document.body).on("click", "a.woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link", this.toggle_terms)
        },
        toggle_terms: function() {
            if (g(".woocommerce-terms-and-conditions").length)
                return g(".woocommerce-terms-and-conditions").slideToggle(function() {
                    var e = g(".woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link");
                    g(".woocommerce-terms-and-conditions").is(":visible") ? (e.addClass("woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link--open"),
                    e.removeClass("woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link--closed")) : (e.removeClass("woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link--open"),
                    e.addClass("woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link--closed"))
                }),
                !1
        }
    };
    v.init(),
    e.init(),
    t.init(),
    o.init()
});
```

Comment: it looks like an error message from woocommerce it self (the file is //wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.min.js), it might not be an issue if the orders are closed anyway.

Is it possible to close an order and buy the books?

Comment: Yes so you can still go through and buy the book, it's just the total amount won't show the correct amount until the next screen once you've clicked proceed to Paypal. So ideally it would be automatically updating once you change the country so people can see the correct price before buying.